# Make the Login Button the default in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I know about the `FindControl` BUT my button is inside a Login control which is inside a LoginView control,below is my code but its not working!!

```
Login log = LoginView1.FindControl("Login1") as Login;
Button logButton = log.FindControl("LoginButton") as Button;
this.Form.DefaultButton = logButton.UniqueID;
```

Th error I get is

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: `FindControl` only looks at the immediate children.  You'd need to recursively navigate all the children, the children's children, etc., to find the  control you're looking for.

Comment: I actually have an example of this on this site: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19313306/2084315

Comment: Can you post the aspx markup please?

Comment: Just wondering: Is the login button ID dynamic?
In what event are you executing this code?

Answer (score 0):

FindControl only looks at the immediate children. You'd need to recursively navigate all the children, the children's children, etc., to find the control you're looking for.

```
public Control MyFindControl(Control parent, string controlIdToFind)
{
    foreach(Control c in parent.Controls)
    {
        Control found = MyFindControl(c, controlIdToFind);
        if (found != null)
        {
           return found;
        }
    }

    // control not found.
    return null;
}
```

Then change your code to:

```
Button logButton = (Button) MyFindControl(LoginView1, "LoginButton");

if (logButton != null)
{
    this.Form.DefaultButton = logButton.UniqueID;
}
```

Comment: there may be some additional work for user controls, but this is the basic approach

Comment: Thanks this looks great but this still only looks at the LoginView and not at the Login Control inside the LoginView where the button is.. or im I missing something?